# Ubuntu 22.04. Wifi disconnects

Tags: drivers, wireless, 22.04, hp, connection

**SITUATION**
I recently bought my HP 15s-fq5099ns without SO and installed Ubuntu 22.04 (LTS).
**PROBLEM**
The PC seems to connect correctly to WiFi, but from time to time (in 5 minutes time lapses) it stops working. It doesn't really disconnect, it just stops working.
I've noticed it usually disconnects when trying to download big files. In fact,  when I try to install git, it cannot connect to es.archive.ubuntu.com, so I cancel the proccess, but then it says there is a caché lock caused by the proccess of "sudo apt install git" and does not let me kill the proccess. Moreover, whenever I try to ping any domain, WiFi stops working too.

**WIRELESS INFO SCRIPT**

########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 08 Nov 2023 07:29 CET +0100

Booted last: 08 Nov 2023 00:00 CET +0100

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

###### release

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

###### kernel

Linux 6.2.0-36-generic #37~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Oct  9 15:34:04 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

###### desktop

Ubuntu

###### lspci

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c822]
DeviceName: Realtek RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Adaptor + BT5
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:85f7]

###### lsusb

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b75e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP TrueVision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b00c Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

###### PCMCIA card info

###### rfkill

1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no

###### secure boot

SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode

###### lsmod

mac80211             1617920  2 rtw88_pci,rtw88_core
cfg80211             1241088  2 rtw88_core,mac80211
hp_wmi                 24576  0
platform_profile       16384  1 hp_wmi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
sparse_keymap          16384  2 hp_wmi,intel_hid
wmi                    40960  3 hp_wmi,video,wmi_bmof

###### interfaces

###### ifconfig

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback  brd 
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether <MAC 'wlo1' [IF1]> brd 
altname wlp1s0
inet 192.168.1.90/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlo1
valid_lft 86331sec preferred_lft 86331sec
inet6 fe80::d345:a6bd:62f6:4f3b/64 scope link noprefixroute
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

###### iwconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"MiFibra-A3D4"
Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'MiFibra-A3D4' [AN5]>
Bit Rate=104 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm
Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
Power Management:on
Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-39 dBm
Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

###### route

default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp metric 600
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlo1 scope link metric 1000
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.90 metric 600

###### resolv.conf

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search home

###### network managers

Installed:

```
NetworkManager
```

Running:

root         535       1  0 Nov07 ?        00:00:04 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

###### NetworkManager info

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlo1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rtw_8822ce
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.2.0-36-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlo1' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/net/wlo1
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:01:00.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlo1
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     MiFibra-A3D4
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       863cb83b-e341-4b25-9fbf-2ef9d92b1ccf
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/12
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     117 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.MESH:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.IBSS-RSN:               no
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.90/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          home
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name = home
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        expiry = 1699511285
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        host_name = rafael-laptop
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        ip_address = 192.168.1.90
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       wpad =

IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::d345:a6bd:62f6:4f3b/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/4
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   863cb83b-e341-4b25-9fbf-2ef9d92b1ccf | MiFibra-A3D4

SSID                BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  IN-USE
--                  <MAC '--' [AN1]>  Infra  52    5260 MHz  540 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA2      no
MiFibra-A3D4        <MAC 'MiFibra-A3D4' [AN2]>  Infra  52    5260 MHz  540 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA2      no
MOVISTAR_C900       <MAC 'MOVISTAR_C900' [AN3]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  130 Mbit/s  84      ▂▄▆█  WPA2      no
MOVISTAR_PLUS_C900  <MAC 'MOVISTAR_PLUS_C900' [AN4]>  Infra  52    5260 MHz  540 Mbit/s  80      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      no
MiFibra-A3D4        <MAC 'MiFibra-A3D4' [AN5]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  130 Mbit/s  78      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      yes     *
MOVISTAR_C900       <MAC 'MOVISTAR_C900' [AN6]>  Infra  52    5260 MHz  540 Mbit/s  77      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      no
Protozoo            <MAC 'Protozoo' [AN7]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  130 Mbit/s  59      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      no
MOVISTAR_PLUS_397E  <MAC 'MOVISTAR_PLUS_397E' [AN8]>  Infra  52    5260 MHz  540 Mbit/s  49      ▂▄__  WPA2      no
Protozoo            <MAC 'Protozoo' [AN9]>  Infra  52    5260 MHz  540 Mbit/s  49      ▂▄__  WPA2      no

###### NetworkManager.state

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

###### NetworkManager config

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com./

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

###### NetworkManager profiles

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/eduroam.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=eduroam | type=wifi | permissions=user:rafaelmp:;
[wifi] ssid=eduroam
[802-1x] ca-cert=/home/rafaelmp/.config/cat_installer/ca.pem
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MiFibra-A3D4.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=MiFibra-A3D4 | type=wifi
[wifi] ssid=MiFibra-A3D4
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/UCM.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=UCM | type=wifi
[wifi] ssid=UCM
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Livebox6-09D6.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Livebox6-09D6 | type=wifi
[wifi] ssid=Livebox6-09D6
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

###### Netplan config

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
version: 2
renderer: NetworkManager

###### iw reg get

'iw' is not installed (package "iw").

###### iwlist channels

lo        no frequency information.

wlo1      32 channels in total; available frequencies :
Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
Current Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

###### iwlist scan

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlo1      Interface doesn't support scanning : Device or resource busy

###### module infos

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.2.0-36-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
depends:        cfg80211,libarc4
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       6.2.0-36-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.2.0-36-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
depends:
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       6.2.0-36-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

###### module parameters

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

###### /etc/modules

###### modprobe options

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi 
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) 
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

###### rc.local

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

###### pm-utils

###### udev rules

###### dmesg

[29004.054934] rtw_8822ce 0000:01:00.0: firmware failed to report density after scan
[29334.525766] wlo1: authenticate with <MAC 'MiFibra-A3D4' [AN5]>
[29335.002785] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'MiFibra-A3D4' [AN5]> (try 1/3)
[29335.006288] wlo1: authenticated
[29335.008818] wlo1: associate with <MAC 'MiFibra-A3D4' [AN5]> (try 1/3)
[29335.016010] wlo1: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'MiFibra-A3D4' [AN5]> (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=1)
[29335.016550] wlo1: associated
[29335.077089] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by <MAC 'MiFibra-A3D4' [AN5]>
[29434.404679] rtw_8822ce 0000:01:00.0: firmware failed to leave lps state (repeated 2 times)
[29465.323918] rtw_8822ce 0000:01:00.0: firmware failed to report density after scan
[29466.449416] wlo1: authenticate with <MAC 'MiFibra-A3D4' [AN2]>
[29466.990927] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'MiFibra-A3D4' [AN2]> (try 1/3)
[29466.998561] wlo1: authenticated
[29467.000476] wlo1: associate with <MAC 'MiFibra-A3D4' [AN2]> (try 1/3)
[29467.004593] wlo1: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'MiFibra-A3D4' [AN2]> (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=35)
[29467.005424] wlo1: associated
[29467.100796] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 127 (127 - 0) dBm as advertised by <MAC 'MiFibra-A3D4' [AN2]>
[29473.202895] rtw_8822ce 0000:01:00.0: firmware failed to leave lps state (repeated 5 times)
[29510.333242] rtw_8822ce 0000:01:00.0: firmware failed to report density after scan
[29514.894381] wlo1: authenticate with <MAC 'MiFibra-A3D4' [AN2]>
[29515.235300] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'MiFibra-A3D4' [AN2]> (try 1/3)
[29515.238945] wlo1: authenticated
[29515.243128] wlo1: associate with <MAC 'MiFibra-A3D4' [AN2]> (try 1/3)
[29515.247134] wlo1: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'MiFibra-A3D4' [AN2]> (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=35)
[29515.248164] wlo1: associated
[29515.331503] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 127 (127 - 0) dBm as advertised by <MAC 'MiFibra-A3D4' [AN2]>
[29515.375501] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
[29547.183766] rtw_8822ce 0000:01:00.0: firmware failed to leave lps state (repeated 6 times)
[29585.362834] rtw_8822ce 0000:01:00.0: firmware failed to report density after scan
[29586.400007] wlo1: authenticate with <MAC 'MiFibra-A3D4' [AN5]>
[29586.901710] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'MiFibra-A3D4' [AN5]> (try 1/3)
[29586.905224] wlo1: authenticated
[29586.907289] wlo1: associate with <MAC 'MiFibra-A3D4' [AN5]> (try 1/3)
[29586.915443] wlo1: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'MiFibra-A3D4' [AN5]> (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=1)
[29586.916037] wlo1: associated
[29587.176028] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by <MAC 'MiFibra-A3D4' [AN5]>

########## wireless info END ############

Comment: Please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and edit the question to include the wireless script result